# How does Physical RAM affects file copy?

Tags: networking, memory, ssd, file-transfer, windows-server-2012

**My setup:**

*Source and destination Servers (installed in M1000e Dell enclosure):*

- Dell Poweredge M620 (Blade servers)
- 2x Intel E5-2650 @ 2GHz
  processors
- 192GB RAM (DDR3, 1333Mhz
- Perc H310 Raid controller
  (6Gbe per slot)
- 2x 1.7TB SSD (Sata) drives (RAID-0)
- 2x 10Gbe NICs
  (MS-Team, Switch independent, Dynamic, All adapters active)
- Windows 2012 R2 (Default  installation)
- System Managed Page file
- Servers are connected to Internal enclosure's Force10 MXL 10Gb switch
- Jumbo packets are configured (NICs and Switch ports)

**Use Case:**

When copying (windows copy) a large file (over 200GB) between source and destination servers (doesn't matter in which direction -happens in both), copy start with a nice solid transfer rate of ~1GB/s (even though i was expecting ~2GB/s), however, somewhere along the way it  drops to a few MB/s (!) for the rest of the transfer.
**Please see the below image for a clearer view**

[image]

It looks like RAM is affecting my copy action.
How and why does it affects it?

Comment: Try it with [FastCopy](https://fastcopy.jp/en/) which uses low-level API and avoids many mechanisms used by Explorer, even the cache, so it can achieve better speeds. This will indicate whether the problem is with the cache.

Answer (score 0):

- The bandwidth between the servers is 10Gbit/s.
- The bandwidth to your SSDs is 6Gbit/s, of which ca 4Gbit are net write speed

So in the first phase, the file data comes in at close 10Gbit/s, of which 4Gbit/s are moved on to disk, while 4Gbit/s stay in the cache.

After ca. 100s half of your cache has filled, so Windows starts throttling the transfer, but still the incoming data plus the cache flush are more than the SSDs can handle. This results in more cache fillup.

When the free RAM finally hits the lower limit (or the dirty cache size the upper limit), Windows will throttle the transfer to nearly zero to allow the cache flush to catch up.

When all dirty data has been moved, the transfer speed will pick up again and an equilibrium is reached (unless the transfer is over).

To move large files, it is much better to use software that uses file writes with `O_DIRECT`, which of course Explorer doesn't.

Comment: A "few MB/s" is a bit extreme for that scenario.

Comment: It is. But that's the way Windows Explorer works. Use something more fit for the purpose.